# Overlaying two sections with CSS

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, css-selectors, margin

I'm working in a design and I need to overlay one section over other keeping a curve like this
[Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNPhY.png)

So I've created two sections first (blue) and second (gray), and looks like this
[Pre CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xq5M.png)

I am using the property translateY to raise the second section but it covers the first, and I lose the curve
[post Css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1NUY.png)

I've tried using property z-index, but it seems not work, I' dont want to use property position: absolute/relative, beacuse are different sections. Any one comes with something?

Comment: Please create a snippet which shows the problem see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I've tried using property z-index, but it seems not work

To have z-index work for you, **position property must not be static**. As stated in [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_z-index.asp):

> Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position: absolute, position: relative, position: fixed, or position: sticky) and flex items (elements that are direct children of display: flex elements).

I couldn't check as you didn't provide a fiddle, was your CSS for the sections have a position like this?

```
.section-1 { position: relative; z-index:1; }
.section-2 { position: relative; z-index:2; }
```

Comment: It had default position (I guess static). Giving property position: relative, it works how I wanted. A big thanks you to you. Has been very useful!!